# Adding two orderer node's IP addresses, when creating multi node channel in Hyperledger fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

After creating one organization and create same organization on multi nodes. I am trying to create a channel. I separated orderers for 2 orderers one node to another 2 orderer to another node. Therefore when one node is crashed other orderer node will work. But when I create a channel how can I give two IP addresses of orderers.

Because It wants one IP address.

`peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME \`

Comment: Please somebody explain to me how can I do it or I can't do it.

Comment: fine I will do it myself and I will write it here. Every single time in stackoverflow same thing happens over and over again

Answer (score 0):

`peer channel create` targets a single ordering service node. That ordering service node should already be in consensus with other ordering service nodes on the system channel. The ordering nodes use the system channel to coordinate on the creation of a new channel. The ordering nodes then reach consensus on the new channel.